# pagination using Rest API in php

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to fetch data from mysql and display them category wise with pagination. I am getting the category wise result but when i change my page data of every category changed too i need to change the data of only category selected . i have setup multi category news option for user so they can add one news to multiple category .help me out here is my code what am trying.

```
<?php

include'../config.php';

// number of rows to show per page
$rowsperpage = 2;


$main = array();
$cat = array();


$qry = "SELECT * FROM app_category order by id DESC ";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
$records = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($rowcount > 1) {
    foreach ($res as $records) {

        $cat = $records;
// lets find out how many rows are in the MySQL table
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_news WHERE cat_id='" . $cat['id'] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $numrows = $r[0];
// find out total pages
        $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

        if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
            $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
        } else {
            $currentpage = 1;  // default page number
        }

        // if current page is greater than total pages
        if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
// set current page to last page
            $currentpage = $totalpages;
        }
// if current page is less than first page
        if ($currentpage < 1) {
// set current page to first page
            $currentpage = 1;
        }
// the offset of the list, based on current page
        $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;


        $qry = "SELECT * FROM app_news where cat_id='" . $cat['id'] . "' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
        $res1 = mysqli_query($con, $qry);

        $json1 = array();

        while ($records1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $news_id = $records1['news_id'];
            $news_title = $records1['title'];
            $news_des = $records1['description'];
            $news_des = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $news_des));
            $news_image = $records1['image'];

            $json1[] = array("news_id" => $news_id, "title" => $news_title, "image" => $imgapi . $news_image, "description" => $news_des);
        }
        $cat['All-news'] = array("total no of pages" => $totalpages, "data" => $json1);
        $main[] = $cat;
        unset($json1);
        unset($json);
        unset($cat);
    }
    unset($totalpages);
//header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($main, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    unset($main);
    mysqli_close($con);
} else {
    $minfo = array("success" => 'false', "message" => 'No result to display. Please add First category.');
    $jsondata = json_encode($minfo);
    print_r($jsondata);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have Split my code in two request get and post 
get is for first time initialisation and then i use post method for getting scroll amount from app:

**here is code :**

```
<?php

include'../config.php';
$main = array();
$cat = array();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {


    $rowsperpage = 5;
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM app_category order by id DESC ";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    $records = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if ($rowcount > 1) {
        foreach ($res as $records) {

            $cat = $records;
// lets find out how many rows are in the MySQL table
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_news WHERE cat_id='" . $cat['id'] . "'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $numrows = $r[0];
// find out total pages
            $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

            if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
                $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
            } else {
                $currentpage = 1;  // default page number
            }

            // if current page is greater than total pages
            if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
// set current page to last page
                $currentpage = $totalpages;
            }
// if current page is less than first page
            if ($currentpage < 1) {
// set current page to first page
                $currentpage = 1;
            }
// the offset of the list, based on current page
            $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;


            $qry = "SELECT * FROM app_news where cat_id='" . $cat['id'] . "' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
            $res1 = mysqli_query($con, $qry);

            $json1 = array();

            while ($records1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $news_id = $records1['news_id'];
                $news_title = $records1['title'];
                $news_des = $records1['description'];
                $news_des = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $news_des));
                $news_image = $records1['image'];

                $json1[] = array("news_id" => $news_id, "title" => $news_title, "image" => $imgapi . $news_image, "description" => $news_des);
            }
            $cat['All-news'] = array("total no of pages" => $totalpages, "data" => $json1);
            $main[] = $cat;
            unset($json1);
            unset($json);
            unset($cat);
        }
        unset($totalpages);
//header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($main, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        unset($main);
        mysqli_close($con);
    } else {
        $minfo = array("success" => 'false', "message" => 'No result to display. Please add First category.');
        $jsondata = json_encode($minfo);
        print_r($jsondata);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        exit();
    }
}




if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    include_once'../config.php';
    if (isset($_POST['cat_id'])) {
        $rowsperpage = 5;
        $catid = $_POST['cat_id'];
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM app_category WHERE id='" . $catid . "' ";
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $cat=$row;
        }
// lets find out how many rows are in the MySQL table
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_news WHERE cat_id='" . $cat['id'] . "'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $numrows = $r[0];
// find out total pages
            $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);
            ///Checkeing for page requested
            if (isset($_POST['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_POST['currentpage'])) {
                $currentpage = (int) $_POST['currentpage'];
            } else {
                $currentpage = 1;  // default page number
            }
            // if current page is greater than total pages
            if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
// set current page to last page
                $currentpage = $totalpages;
            }
// if current page is less than first page
            if ($currentpage < 1) {
// set current page to first page
                $currentpage = 1;
            }
// the offset of the list, based on current page
            $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

            $qry = "SELECT * FROM app_news where cat_id='" . $catid . "' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
            $res1 = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
            $json1 = array();

            while ($records1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $news_id = $records1['news_id'];
                $news_title = $records1['title'];
                $news_des = $records1['description'];
                $news_des = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $news_des));
                $news_image = $records1['image'];

                $json1[] = array("news_id" => $news_id, "title" => $news_title, "image" => $imgapi . $news_image, "description" => $news_des);
            }
            $cat['All-news'] = array("total no of pages" => $totalpages, "data" => $json1);
            $main[] = $cat;
            unset($json1);
            unset($json);
            unset($cat);


        echo json_encode($main, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        unset($main);
        unset($totalpages);
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```